# Find the number of 4 digital numbers whose greatest common divisor with 18 is 3

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I found this question shared by another student in my Maths doubt group.As the question says,we have to find the total number of 4-digit numbers whose greatest common divisor with 18 is 3.

Here's what I tried:-

Find total number of 4 digit numbers divisible by 3.
The numbers are :- 1002,1005,1008........9999

So by the nth term of an AP formula,we get:-

1002+(n-1)3 = 9999

So n comes out to be 3000.After this I tried to filter out the numbers.

I now divided the entire series by 3.We get:-
334,335,336......3333.

Now the condition to have common divisor with 18 equal to 3 is that the number in the above series shouldn't be divisible by 3 or by 2 I think.

So first of all the even numbers in the series are disqualified.Now we are left with :-
335,337,339......3333,i.e 1500 numbers still remain. Now the numbers divisible by 3 in the above series are:-

339,341...3333.

Therefore number of digits divisible by 3 between 339 and 3333 are 999(using the same nth term of an AP formula I used earlier).

4)In the original series I wrote in step 3,there were 1498 numbers between 339 and 3333, both included.Of this 999 are divisible by 3.Hence we are left with 499.Now we add 2 to this(335,337),and the total final answer comes to be 501.

But the answer key says the answer is 1000. Can someone please tell me what mistakes I have made?

Thanks!

Comment: The numbers whose greatest common divisor with $18$ is $3$ will be precisely those numbers who are odd, who are multiples of $3$, and who are not multiples of $9$.  So, count the odd multiples of $3$ in your desired region.  Subtract the odd multiples of $9$ from that region.

Comment: Just for intuition's sake, every number in the progression $3+18n$ has the right gcd.  Now these have exactly $4$ digits from $n=56$ to $n=555$.  So that's $500$ right there.  But you also have the progression $15+18n$ to consider.

Comment: The desired numbers are those of the form $18n+3$ or $18n+15$.  Now just compute how many of each of those lie in the admissible range.

Comment: Thanks everyone,I understood the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You were OK until the last step.  When you count multiples of 3 in the sequence $335, 337, 339, 341, 343, ... , 3333$ you must assume they are six units apart because you dropped out all the even numbers.  The smallest multiple of 3 in this list is $339$, the largest is $3333$.  Then $[(3333-339)/6]+1=500$ which, subtracted from the $1500$ numbers surviving the previous steps, properly leaves $1000$.

Comment: Thanks!The series you mentioned should start with 335 no?